# Can you create this fading strip using only CSS?

Tags: css, user-interface

Can I create this using css?

[image]

there's some box-shadow css I can use to create the bottom border, but how do you create the effect on the left and right sides?

Comment: look at linear-gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can: https://jsfiddle.net/0mro5t77/

The trick is to use an outer and an inner container. The outer container provides the white background for the bar and the box shadow. The inner container has a gradient "page background color -> transparent -> page background color" and is positioned absolutely so it overlaps the outer container to create the fading effect.

```
html, body {
    background: #ccc;
}
.outer {
    box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px -20px #333, 0 20px 20px -20px #333;
    background: #fff;
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, #ccc 100%);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -25px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```